# how to call jquery click event manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Below is HTML:

```
    <div class="accordianDiv">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2">document tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab3">tab 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Following is click event code:

```
   //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        alert(activeTab);
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });
```

On click of any HREF, it works fine and execute above jquery stuff.

Now, I need to execute above jquery stuff manually using jquery example, call the click event for `HREF[#TAB1/2/3]`. Please guide me on this how can i call jquery event manually.

Meaning - when need to select tab1 then, it click event should call for tab1 same as for tab 2 and tab 3 accordinlgy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I understood you need call trigger function

```
$("ul.tabs li").trigger('click')
$('ul.tabs li a[href="#tab2"]').trigger('click')
```

P.S. Change your html, and add class tabs to ul. [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zibuw/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a trigger

```
$("ul.tabs li").trigger('click');
```

Or the short version:

```
$("ul.tabs li").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find corresponding `a` element and then trigger click event on it:

```
var tab = "tab2";
$("ul.tabs li a[href='#" + tab + "']").click();
```

Even though you trigger event on `a`, it will anyway bubble to parent `li` handler.

Comment: tried, but not executed, i added alert in click event , it calls when manually clikc at href but, did not call when use manual click event as you mented. plz guide.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var i, len,
  tabsToClick = [ 'tab1', 'tab2', 'tab3' ];

for ( i = 0, len = tabsToClick.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    $( '[href="#'+ tabsToClick[ i ] +'"]' ).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectTab(tab) {
    $("ul.tabs li a[href='#" + tab + "']").trigger("click");
}
```